# ASP gridview not updating database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, gridview

When I click Edit on a row in the gridview, it shows the data like it should.  It shows the text boxes where I expect to see them and it allows me to modify the data in the box.  When I click Update on that row it does the same thing as cancel; the page refills without saving any data changes.  The database is also unchanged.

```
<%@ Page Title="Employee Lookup"Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmployeeLookup.aspx.cs" Inherits="WSC.EmployeeLookup" %>
<p>
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="5" Width="442px">
        <asp:TableRow>           
        <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="NewUserButton" PostBackUrl="~/EmployeeInfo.aspx" runat="server" Text="New Employee" /></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="eID"
         AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" 
         EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True">            
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="eID" HeaderText="Employee ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="eID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="eFirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="eFirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="eLastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="eLastName" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="JobTitle" SortExpression="eJobTitle">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" width="50" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eJobTitle") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("eJobTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept Code" SortExpression="deptNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" width="50" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("deptNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("deptNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="eUserName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" width="50" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eUserName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("eUserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="ePassword">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" width="70" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ePassword") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="*********"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="eEmail">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eEmail") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("eEmail") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hire Date" SortExpression="eDateHire">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eDateHire") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("eDateHire") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="securityID" SortExpression="securityID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("securityID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("securityID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="ErrorMessageLabel" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>

    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" DataFile="C:\WSC\WSC\WSC\CIS470_Database.accdb"            
        SelectCommand="SELECT `eID`, `eFirstName`, `eLastName`, `eJobTitle`, `deptNumber`, `eUserName`, `ePassword`, `eEmail`, `eDateHire`, `securityID` FROM `Employee`"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE `Employee` SET `eFirstName` = ?, `eLastName` = ?, `eJobTitle` = ?, `deptNumber` = ?, `eUserName` = ?, `ePassword` = ?, `eEmail` = ?, `eDateHire` = ?, `securityID` = ? WHERE `eID` = ?">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="eID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="eFirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="eLastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="eJobTitle" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="deptNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="eUserName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ePassword" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="eEmail" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ePhone" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="eDateHire" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="eDateTerm" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="securityID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
</p>
```

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044683/how-do-i-update-an-an-access-database-from-a-gridview-in-visual-studio/43772410#43772410

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="eID" Type="Int32" />
```

To:

```
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="eFirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="eLastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="eJobTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="deptNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="eUserName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ePassword" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="eEmail" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="eDateHire" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="eDateTerm" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="securityID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

And use:

```
eFirstName = @eFirstName, ... WHERE eID = @eID"
```

instead of what you are using in your UpdateCommand. The problem is you parameters must start with @ in your update and deletecommand. Then they will much the parameters between

```
<DeleteParameters></DeleteParameters>
```

And

```
<UpdateParameters></UpdateParameters>
```